# HTML mailto form

Tags: html, forms, email

Can anyone help me with my feedback form for a website I am building? 
I am not receiving any errors when I run this, although it doesn't actually send any email at all.
The following is the code I am trying to use:

```
<form action="mailto:admin@example.com" enctype="text/plain" method="post">
<p>Name: <input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" size="40"></p>
<p>E-mail address: <input name="E-mail" type="text" id="E-mail" size="40"></p>
<p>Comment:</p>
<p><textarea name="Comment" cols="55" rows="5"
id="Comment"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Your question needs to ask about a specific problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I am trying to have a feedback form, which sends an email to the admin of the site using the above code. But it is not working.

Comment: Then edit your question with information on what specifically does not work. You need to include the error message, and the back-end code that handles the form input.

Also, it is advised to never have dash `-` characters in the form attribute name `<input name="E-mail"` should be more like `<input name="Email"`

Comment: Using a `mailto:` link as the action of an HTML form is not a very good idea. It will only work if the client is using a system that has email client software already installed, and if that is the case, you may as well just put your email address in an ordinary link (`<a href="mailto:admin@example.com">Send me an email</a>`) so your visitors can use their email software instead of having to type into a textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Sending mail from `HTML Form` is not a right option to do, you are using an `HTTP Method (POST)`, so you have to set a `http/https` link from your action value. Otherwise, you have to send the email using the `href` tag, including a subject and body parameters.

E.g: `<a href="mailto:admin@example.com?subject=SUBJECT&body=MESSAGE">Send Message</a>`

The mail application installed in your machine would automatically opened when you click that link.`(Outlook, Gmail,...)` and you can choose which one you have to send the mail within it.

Answer (score 0):

you should maken a .php file 
eg.

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
```

then in your mail.php put something like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

$to = "contact@webmagico.be"; // this is your Email address
$from = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); // this is the sender's Email address
$naam = htmlspecialchars($_POST['naam']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);

$messageText = $naam . " " . $email . " wrote:" . "\n\n" . htmlspecialchars($_POST['bericht']);

$message = array(
  "ontvanger" => $to,
  "zender" => $from,
  "naam" => $naam,
  "email" => $email
);

$valid = true;

foreach($item in $message)
{
  if(!isset($item) || $item === "")
  {
    $valid = false;
  }
}

if($valid)
{
  mail($to, $naam, $message, "From:" . $email);
}
else
{
  $_SESSION['error'] = "Forgot something!"
}

/*file that gives the response*/
header('Location: thankyou.php');


?>
```

You can find different alternatives about a post-form on the web. 
Hope this helps.