# How to submit contact form and recieve Email in HTML

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
  <title>Contact Us</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="MAILTO: xyz@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain"></form>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>contact us form</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-form">
      <div class="input-fields">
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Name" required>
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Email Address" required>
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Phone" required>
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Subject" required>
      </div>
      <div class="msg">
        <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
        <!-- <div class="btn">send</div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Hi! I am trying to make a contact form but i am not able to receive the Email send by the form....actually it never sends the data...what can i do? I want to receive the data on my gmail when the user clicks the send Button.

Comment: You are closing the `</form>`

Comment: Do not put you actual email in the question for security and privacy.

Comment: It is still not Working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML mailto form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366428/html-mailto-form)

Comment: Replace this line `<form action="MAILTO: xyz@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain"></form>` with `<form action="mailto:xyz@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">`

Comment: don't close `form` on the first line

Answer (score -1):

There is a closing tag at the end of the line where you start your form.

```
 <form action="MAILTO: xyz@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>contact us form</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-form">
      <div class="input-fields">
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Name" required>
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Email Address" required>
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Phone" required>
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Subject" required>
      </div>
      <div class="msg">
        <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
        <!-- <div class="btn">send</div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

Try the above instead.

On top of this - all this code will do is open a client on your computer for the user to then send an email direct. It won't submit a message direct to the user from the browser. If you wish to do that, you will have to use back-end code. I suggest Node.js and Nodemailer. Here's a good link explaining that:

https://blog.mailtrap.io/nodemailer-gmail/

Comment: Its just a TYPO by OP not an actual issue here.